# How do IntelliJ Idea and Netbeans build java projects?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, ant, intellij-idea

How do IntelliJ Idea and Netbeans build java projects? Do they use Ant or Maven or their own build tool?

Comment: Intellij supports [both](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ant_maven.html).

Comment: @Vic if I create a simple java project in Intellij ,what will be used by default? Maven or ant?
Like netbeans use Ant by default

Comment: I believe it uses the usual javac compilation. Its configurable in Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

netbeans is using ant
http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/

Comment: NetBeans can also use Maven (File -> Open Project...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the question wasn't if the IDE can use the build tool X, but rather if the IDE itself is built with Ant or Maven. In fact, NetBeans can be built with Maven too.

Comment: @AntonArhipov: that's not how I understand that question. I do think Raheel wants to know what the IDE uses to build projects that are developed *using* the IDE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Exactly I wanted to know what IntelliJ and Netbeans uses to build projects
And thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Build tools are programs that automate the creation of executable applications from source code(eg. .apk for android app). Building incorporates compiling,linking and packaging the code into a usable or executable form. 
default build tool used in netbeans is 'ant'